# recursion confusion - rod cutting algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to implement the rod cutting algorithm illustrated in CLRS, but I find myself having a hard time getting the indices correct. Here is my implementation of the memoization version:

```
import sys
def rod_cutting_memoization(p,n):
    r = [None for i in range(n+1)]
    r[0] = 0
    rod_cutting_memoization_aux(p,n,r)
    return r

def rod_cutting_memoization_aux(p,n,r):
    print r
    if r[n] is not None:
        return r[n]
    if n is 0:
        return 0
    else:
        q = -100
        for i in range(n):
            q = max(q, p[i] + rod_cutting_memoization_aux(p,n-i-1,r))
    r[n] = q

p=[1, 5, 8, 9, 10, 17, 17, 20, 24, 30]
n = int(sys.argv[1])
print rod_cutting_memoization(p,n)
```

Starting from n=2, the code is saying int + None. The pseudo code in the book was written with index staring from 1. I always have this issue with converting algorithm with indexing from 1 to 0. Is there a general approach to solve this?

Comment: Don't use `is 0`; CPython may intern integers but this is not a given and guaranteed behaviour. Use `if n == 0:` or `if not n:` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your recursive `rod_cutting_memoization_aux()` function only returns values for `r[n] is not None` and for `n == 0`. If neither of those conditions is `True`, then the function just ends without an explicit `return`, which means `None` is returned instead.

This means that the line:

```
q = max(q, p[i] + rod_cutting_memoization_aux(p,n-i-1,r))
```

will try to sum `p[i]` with `None` for some values of `p, n - i - 1, r`.

You need to return *something other than `None`* from the recursive call to prevent this; presumably an integer needs to be returned.